# Issue multiplying two string values in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have two values which are of type String in my labels. I'm trying to multiply these values. When I multiply them I get error or found nil value. I have tried this code:

```
let percentage = (Int(self.subTotalLbl.text!)! * Int(self.totalDiscount)) / 100
print(self.perTotal)
let grandTotal = Int(self.subTotalLbl.text!)! - percentage
self.grandTotalLbl.text =  String(grandTotal)
```

I'm confused why it is showing nil values. I have used breakpoints. Also values are going fine but when they are passed to percentage it crashes the app.

Comment: Most of the `!` in your code are bad and need to be replaced with proper optional handling.

Comment: You also need to clarify what the exact and complete error message are and which lines are causing them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to properly handle optional values and converting strings to numbers.

```
if let text = self.subTotalLbl.text, let subtotal = Int(text) {
    let percentage = subtotal * Int(self.totalDiscount) / 100
    let grandTotal = subTotal - percentage
    self.grandTotalLbl.text = "\(grandTotal)"
}
```

I am assuming that `self.totalDiscount` is some numeric data type.

If `self.totalDiscount` is a `String` for some strange reason, the code needs to be:

```
if let text = self.subTotalLbl.text, let subtotal = Int(text), let discount = Int(self.totalDiscount) {
    let percentage = subtotal * discount / 100
    let grandTotal = subTotal - percentage
    self.grandTotalLbl.text = "\(grandTotal)"
}
```

Comment: self.totalDiscount its a string value and i'm converting that to Int

Comment: Why is `totalDiscount` a `String`? Store numbers as numbers, not strings.

Comment: The values are coming from backend as a string so that why i'm converting them to Int.. @rmaddy

Comment: i have used breakpoint in ur answer but it does not go inside the if statement. @rmaddy

Comment: Then this means one or more of the following is true: 1. `self.subTotalLbl.text` is nil. 2. `self.subTotalLbl.text` contains a string that is not an integer. 3. The string in `self.totalDiscount` is not an integer. Note that both strings need to be integers. They can't be decimals. If you want to handle all of this as decimals instead of integers, replace `Int` with `Double` in all of this code.

Comment: Why don't you just show us what you have in self.subTotalLbl.text right before the if statement?

Comment: @LeoDabus That applies to `UITextField`, not `UILabel`. I confirmed that before posting the answer. `UILabel text` can be `nil`.

Comment: Ok so it makes no sense to use the UI to pass values around

Comment: I didn't get my answer in ur answer. @rmaddy

Comment: Did you read the last comment left for you? What was the result? Which of these three conditions are true? And it will be a lot easier to help if you update your question showing the actual values for each of the values involved.